# Save the changes that Javacript made in the DOM to the html file

Tags: javascript

I have a local HTML file that uses scripts to add additional content to the page.

It sort of works like journal entries. Text is entered and submitted, new entries appear with the date and time. I would like those changes to persist within the file. The page is not uploaded anywhere, it's all done locally, so security etc is not a concern.

What I would like most is for them to be saved within the index.html itself. I know localstorage is something that can be used to a similiar effect (though not exactly what I am getting at), however from the documentation I can understand how to save some particular values, not really sure how to store entire nodes (a span with a heading, the date, image and entered text) using localstorage.

The code I tried with localstorage is:

```
let entries = document.getElementById('entries'); 
localStorage.allEntries=`${entries}`
document.getElementById("entries").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("allEntries");
```

What I get on the page is "[object HTMLDivElement]" instead of the entries made. CBroe below said that it is possible to store the innerHTML of elements so there must be something wrong with the above code.

Comment: Your question is quite ambiguous. What do you mean by "entire nodes"? What have you tried so far to save in local storage? Please share code you have written to make this work and what particular issues you are facing while doing that.

Comment: _“not really sure how to store entire nodes using localstorage”_ - well ideally, you would store only the _data_ that is necessary to render them in the first place - and then have a script go over that data, and create the necessary element(s), based on that data. But of course you can also store the complete innerHTML/outerHTML of complete elements as well, if you like.

Comment: _“What I would like most is for them to be saved within the index.html itself.”_ - without any server-side component, the only way to achieve that, is to present the modified page to the user as a _download_ – they would have to manually make sure that they overwrite the existing file on the machine then (and not store it somewhere else/under a different name.)

Comment: You can only store text in localStorage and sessionStorage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work, and for anyone with the same problem:

I put the following in the function used to add a new entry, so each time an entry is added, the localstorage gets updated.

```
let entries = document.getElementById('entries').innerHTML; 
localStorage.allEntries=entries //NOT `${entries}`
```

And this at the end of the script, to fetch the content of the storage and replace the innerHTML with it:

```
document.getElementById("entries").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("allEntries");
```

Also if you're having trouble with using localstorage, you might find  this video useful:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIVfDZZeGxM